# Chemical Equilibrium in case of copper(II) ions

Tags: equilibrium

> $\pu{Cu^{2+}}$ ions react with $\pu{Fe^{2+}}$ ions according to the following reaction:
>   $$\ce{Cu^+2 + 2Fe^2+ <=> Cu + 2Fe^3+}$$
>   At equilibrium, the concentration of $\pu{Cu^{2+}}$ ions is not changed by the addition of which ion $\pu{(Cu/Cu^{2+}/Fe^{2+}/Fe^{3+})}$.
>   Explain the result.

Comment: This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one. The homework tag is deprecated, please don't use it.

Comment: I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously $\ce{Cu}$, as it is a solid and has no effect on Equilibrium constant and thus no effect on altering equilibrium concentration of $\ce{Cu^2+}$.

Comment: While we appreciate your contribution to the site, it would be preferable to not answer questions, that do not comply with our [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/).

Answer (score 0):

Cu is the answer. As the concentration of any solid component is fixed and does not effect the Kc value at all.

let concentration = $C$$ , mass = $$m$$ , molar mass = $$M$$ , volume= $$V$$ , density=$$d$$ and no. of moles = $$n$;

then$$C=\frac{n}{V}$$ and $$n=\frac{m}{M}$$ and by the 2 equations we get

$$C=\frac{m}{MV}$$ which equals $$C=\frac{d}{M}$$ and as $$d,V$$ are constant for a solid as Cu, adding more substance would not change its concentration.

Comment: While we appreciate your contribution to the site, it would be preferable to not answer questions, that do not comply with our [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/).